# How do I set the creation time of a node during a migration using the Migrate module?

Tags: 7, migrations

I am building a migration and it is important that each new node has the same creation time stamp as the cosponsoring data in the old system.   How do I set the creation time of a node during a migration using the Migrate module?  I am assuming that it is set by a specific call to `addFieldMapping()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using prepareRow in my class to solve this kind of problem .

First of all I add a new Source Field to the MigrateSourceSQL

```
$source_fields = array(
  'created' => t('the created date'),
```

then in `prepareRow` I added the php for the timestamp and attached it to the row.

```
$row->changed = $nowtimestamp;
```

And then assign with `addFieldMapping`

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_created_date', 'changed' );
```

This seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your migration module and activating it, you will find one or more migration entries in your migration menu (found at admin/content/migrate.)  Click on the migration that you are working on.  On the next screen, click on the Destination link in the sidebar menu.

This will display a list of all available migration field names, including creation time.